# Crash with reading Int32 with Swift 2 and core data

Tags: swift, core-data, crash, int32

Trying to read data in Swift (2) from an NSDictionary with Xcode 7.3 I came across the infamous EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXCI386_INVOP,subcode=0X0) error when trying this:

```
let aDict = data as! NSDictionary
car.tempo = aDict["tempo"] as! Int32
```

No compiler warnings though. I am aware that there were issues with Xcode, Swift and Int32s in the past. Any suggestions how to handle this better? TIA!

Since it wasn't clear maybe - data as shown above is guaranteed to contain data from a plist file and aDict["tempo"] is an NSNumber.

Comment: "Use the forced form of the type cast operator (as!) only when you are sure that the downcast will always succeed. This form of the operator will trigger a runtime error if you try to downcast to an incorrect class type."

Comment: Or to put it another way, any time you use `!` you're pretty much asking for a crash, so you need to be **really** sure about what you're doing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. There was no issue regarding the data and if so there should not have been a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXCI386_INVOP,subcode=0X0) error. This is apparently a bug in Xcode and I will file a radar. 
Reformulating like below does work in Xcode 7.3 as NSNumber gets unwrapped as an Int32:

```
car.tempo = (aDict["tempo"]?.intValue)!
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Well no, because you changed what the code is doing to avoid the issue. This isn't a bug in Xcode, it's a bug in your code that you fixed. Before you were attempting to downcast `NSNumber` to `Int32`, which is impossible, but the `as!` forced the issue so the code crashed. Now you're calling `intValue` on the `NSNumber`, which means you're asking for the `NSNumber`'s integer value instead of trying to force an object to downcast to a primitive type. Incidentally this is **exactly** what @PetahChristian and I described in our comments.

Comment: Congrats on the double down vote! Your original comments just stated that exclamation marks are dangerous. Had you stated that a downcast from an NSNumber to an Int32 is impossible - different story. But what you said was obviously not helpful in the least.

Comment: I didn't downvote this question or your answer. My comment didn't mention `NSNumber` because you didn't indicate that you were using one. Using a `!` is always taking a major risk of a crash, which is why I said that you needed to be sure about what you were doing. Clearly you were not, but your code change fixed it. The original issue is still a bug in your code and not in Xcode.

Comment: Apologies then! Thought it would have been clear that a numeric value in an NSDictionary had to be an NSNumber. Being new to Swift I was wrongly under the impression that unwrapping via NSNumber as! Int32 was equivalent to using intValue on it. I will have to review bridging of NSNumber to Int, etc. I am aware of the inherent dangers of the ! operator, but am still getting used to the different set and sometimes lack of compiler warnings in Swift. In any case the bug got fixed and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You did not set value to aDict for key "tempo"...